# locally algebraic representations

Tags: representation-theory, algebraic-number-theory, galois-representations

Let $K$ be a number field. Consider

$$ \rho_{\ell}: \mathrm{Gal}(\bar K/K) \longrightarrow \mathrm{GL}(V)$$

an $\ell$-adic Galois representation. Assume it is semi-simple rational and abelian.

Is it true that $\rho_{\ell}$ is locally algebraic?